# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory'

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, config

I am getting this error message:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;

I have one Employee entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float salary;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(float salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

In my spring-config.xml file I am not getting the class path in the value attribute in the annotationsession factory bean.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

        <bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/srikanth" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
               <value>Employee</value>
           </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                hibernate.show_sql=true
            </value>
        </property>

    </bean>


    <bean id="employeeDao" class="EmployeeDao">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

This is my main:

```
public class InsertTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");

        EmployeeDao employeeDao = (EmployeeDao) context.getBean("employeeDao");

        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.setId(114);
        e.setName("varun");
        e.setSalary(50000);

        employeeDao.saveEmployee(e);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing hibernate properties like this:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

And instead of:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
```

use:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

That should work.